# Как решить квадратное уравнение написанное в виде строки?

Tags: c

Пользователь вводит строку которая является квадратным уравнением,вот так:

```
scanf("%s",string[80]);
```

Вводим,например: `21x^2+3x+5=0`. Нужно считать строку каким-то способом взять из нее a,b,c, то есть 21,3,5, чтобы эти числа были типом double. И потом уже решить квадратное уравнение. В программе можно использовать только библиотеку stdio и только одну функцию из библиотеки math.h - это `sqrt`, больше ничего нельзя.

Уравнение я смогу написать а вот как изьять из строки числа как double понятия не имею.

Comment: Заменить все не-цифры на пробелы, а потом уже высканивать числа (1-е, 3-е и 4-е).

Comment: Понял схему.но не понимаю как именно с ее помощью вывести три числа в три разные переменные типа doble.Если бы вы могли написать.спасибо

Comment: @Akina Все не совсем так просто, ввести же могут (наверно) и `5+3x+21x^2=0`, и `21x^2+3x=-5`, и (наверняка) `21x^2+5=0`, и `21x^2+3x=0`... И это ещё без учета более экзотических вариантов типа `21x^2+2x+x+5=0`.

Comment: Нет,это примитивная задача как бы)Должны ввести точно так же как в примере ax^2+bx+c=0

Comment: смотри как работает scanf — оной более чем достаточно. Хинт: синтаксис формата почти такой же как у printf'а

Comment: Fat-Zer Извини,я вообще не понял о чем речь)

Comment: @Сергей: И что, даже так вводить нельзя: `5x^2-3x-10=0`?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

В данном случае `scanf()` с одной большой форматной строкой, как предложил @Sergey, не подойдёт. Раз члены уравнения могут следовать в любом порядке, то и строку надо считывать частями.

Пусть на входе у нас строка вида `S1+...+SN=0` или `S1+...+SN=<нецелое_число>` (где `Si = <нецелое_число>x`, либо `Si = <нецелое_число>x^<целое_число>`), а на выходе — массив коэффициентов, где индекс массива соответствует нужной степени при коэффициенте.

Важное замечание: так как число может быть сколь угодно большим, то во избежание переполнения строкового буфера мы будем считывать его поциферно. Ну а так как строка сложная, воспользуемся конечным автоматом.

```
#include <stdio.h>

#define bool unsigned char
#define true 1
#define false 0

enum States
{
    // Конечные состояния
    Result_Success,                 // Успешное завершение
    Result_CoefficientCantBeStored, // Ошибка: массив outCoeffs слишком мал
    Result_UnexpectedSymbolInCoeff, // Ошибка: неожиданный символ в коэффициенте
    Result_UnexpectedEndOfPower,    // Ошибка: После знака степени нет самой степени
    Result_UnexpectedEndOfRightSide,// Ошибка: не указана правая часть уравнения

    // Промежуточные состояния
    State_AtCoeffStart,             // Первый символ коэффициента (+/-/цифра)
    State_AtCoeff,                  // Дальнейшие цифры коэффициента
    State_AtX,                      // Буква "икс"
    State_AtPowerCoeffStart,        // Первый символ показателя степени члена
    State_AtPowerCoeff,             // Показатель степени члена
    State_AtRightSideStart,         // Первый символ справа от знака равенства
    State_AtRightSide,              // Дальнейшие цифры справа от знака равенства

    // Первое неконечное состояние (используется при проверке на необходимость выхода)
    FirstInternalState = State_AtCoeffStart
};

/**
 * Функция разбора строки с линейным уравнением и вычленения из неё коэффициентов.
 *
 * Переметры:
 *
 *     in
 *         Дескриптор входного символьного потока.
 *
 *     outCoeffs
 *         Указатель на массив, который будет принимать коэффициенты, считанные
 *         из уравнения. Коэффициент для N-й степени идёт в outCoeffs[N].
 *         Если определённый коэффициент не указан в уравнении, то в соответствующий
 *         элемент массива будет записан положительный ноль.
 *
 *     coeffsCount
 *         Количество элементов в массиве outCoeffs. Если очередная степень приводит
 *         к записи за пределами outCoeffs, функция возвращает
 *         Result_CoefficientCantBeStored.
 *
 * Возвращаемое значение:
 *
 *     Константа из семейства States::Result_*. При возникновении ошибки происходит
 *     возврат кода, отличного от Result_Success; массив outCoeffs при этом содержит
 *     те коэффициенты, которые были успешно считаны целиком до возникновения ошибки.
 */
enum States parse(FILE* in, double* outCoeffs, size_t coeffsCount)
{
    // Зануляем все указанные коэффициенты, вдруг не все из них будут указаны в уравнении
    for(size_t i = 0; i < coeffsCount; ++i)
        outCoeffs[i] = 0.0;

    enum States state = State_AtCoeffStart;
    size_t currentPowCoefficient = 0;
    bool isPositiveCoeff;
    double numBuffer = 0.0;
    bool metDecimalDot = false;
    size_t denomPower = 0;
    // Так как нам может потребоваться попридержать текущий символ до следующего
    // состояния, введём для него промежуточный буфер
    char ch = fgetc(in);
    while(state >= FirstInternalState)
    {
        // Считываем очередной символ и решаем, что с ним делать (решение принимаем
        // с помощью простенького конечного автомата).
        //
        // Да простят меня нелюбители switch-bases FSM, но пробрасывать
        // во вспомогательные функции все параметры и переменные — для учебного
        // примера это, пожалуй, перебор.
        switch(state)
        {
            case State_AtCoeffStart:
                // Сюда мы можем выйти при завершении предыдущего члена.
                // Поэтому именно здесь мы выдаём готовый коэффициент.
                if(coeffsCount > currentPowCoefficient)
                {
                    // Чтобы сместить десятичную точку на denomPower позиций
                    // вправо, мы могли бы воспользоваться pow(). Однако,
                    // для этого потребуется зпрещённая math.h, а потому мы
                    //вынуждены крутить цикл
                    double decimalPointOffseter = 1.0;
                    for(size_t i = 0; i < denomPower; ++i)
                        decimalPointOffseter /= 10.0;

                    outCoeffs[currentPowCoefficient] = numBuffer
                         * (isPositiveCoeff ? 1.0 : -1.0)
                         / decimalPointOffseter;
                }
                else
                    state = Result_CoefficientCantBeStored;

                // Переходим непосредственно к чтению нового члена
                metDecimalDot = false;
                if(ch == '-')
                {
                    numBuffer = 0.0;
                    isPositiveCoeff = false;
                    ch = fgetc(in);
                    state = State_AtCoeff;
                }
                else if(ch == '=')
                {
                    ch = fgetc(in);
                    state = State_AtRightSideStart;
                }
                else if(ch == EOF)
                {
                    state = Result_Success;
                }
                else
                {
                    numBuffer = 0.0;
                    isPositiveCoeff = true;
                    state = State_AtCoeff;
                }
                break;

            case State_AtCoeff:
                if(ch >= '0' && ch <= '9')
                {
                    numBuffer *= 10.0;
                    numBuffer += (float)(int)(ch - '0');
                    ch = fgetc(in);
                    ++denomPower; // Ничего не проверяем, всё равно будет сброс при точке
                }
                else if(ch == 'x')
                {
                    state = State_AtX;
                    ch = fgetc(in);
                }
                else if(ch == '+' || ch == '-' || ch == EOF)
                {
                    // Окончание коэффициента с нулевой степенью. Придерживаем символ
                    currentPowCoefficient = 0;
                    state = State_AtCoeffStart;
                }
                else if(ch == '.')
                {
                    metDecimalDot = true;
                    denomPower = 0;
                }
                else
                    state = Result_UnexpectedSymbolInCoeff;
                break;

            case State_AtX:
                // Подготавливаем аккумулятор для коэффициента
                currentPowCoefficient = 0;
                if(ch == '^')
                {
                    ch = fgetc(in);
                    state = State_AtPowerCoeffStart;
                }
                else
                {
                    // Окончание коэффициента с первой степенью. Придерживаем символ
                    currentPowCoefficient = 1;
                    state = State_AtCoeffStart;
                }
                break;

            case State_AtPowerCoeffStart:
                state = (ch != EOF) ? State_AtPowerCoeff : Result_UnexpectedEndOfPower;
                break;

            case State_AtPowerCoeff:
                if(ch >= '0' && ch <= '9')
                {
                    currentPowCoefficient *= 10.0;
                    currentPowCoefficient += (size_t)(ch - '0');
                    ch = fgetc(in);
                }
                else
                    state = State_AtCoeffStart;

                break;

            case State_AtRightSideStart:
                if(ch == '-')
                {
                    numBuffer = 0.0;
                    isPositiveCoeff = true; // Инверсия знака
                    ch = fgetc(in);
                    state = State_AtRightSide;
                }
                else if(ch == EOF)
                {
                    state = Result_UnexpectedEndOfRightSide;
                }
                else
                {
                    numBuffer = 0.0;
                    isPositiveCoeff = false; // Инверсия знака
                    state = State_AtRightSide;
                }
                break;

            case State_AtRightSide:
                if(ch == EOF)
                {
                    currentPowCoefficient = 0;
                    numBuffer = -numBuffer;

                    // Переходим, чтобы сохранить коэффициент и сразу же выйти
                    state = State_AtCoeffStart;
                }
                else if(ch == '.')
                {
                    metDecimalDot = true;
                    denomPower = 0;
                }
                else
                {
                    numBuffer *= 10.0;
                    numBuffer += (double)(int)(ch - '0');
                    ch = fgetc(in);
                    ++denomPower; // Ничего не проверяем, всё равно будет сброс при точке
                }
                break;
        }
    }
    return state;
}
```

Comment: Arhad ты бог)))))))большое спасибо

Comment: @Сергей: Если ответ вам помог, кроме «спасибо» его надо ещё отметить зелёной галочкой слева.

Comment: VladD  я вообще-то это сделал

Comment: @Сергей: Странно, а где же галочка? (Она должна быть под количеством голосов.)

Comment: @VladD когда я отмечаю полезный ответ,система пишет что мой голос учтен ,но он не влияет на репутацию так как,мои баллы меньше чем 15)

Comment: @Сергей: А вы не путаете оранжевый голос за и зелёную галочку под ним?

Comment: @VladD аа извиняюсь.Я и не знал что на нее можно нажимать)

Comment: @Сергей: Отлично, теперь знаете)

Answer (score 2):

```
scanf("%fx^2+%fx+%f=0", &a, &b, &c);
```

Comment: Из комментариев к вопросу: *@Akina Все не совсем так просто, ввести же могут (наверно) и `5+3x+21x^2=0`, и `21x^2+3x=-5`, и (наверняка) `21x^2+5=0`, и `21x^2+3x=0`... И это ещё без учета более экзотических вариантов типа `21x^2+2x+x+5=0`.*

Comment: **более экзотических вариантов** - тогда  надо писать генратор ОПЗ. Но я как-то сомневаюсь, что это будет адекватной задачей для первокурсника.

Comment: @Arhad: автор вопроса: *«Нет,это примитивная задача как бы)Должны ввести точно так же как в примере ax^2+bx+c=0»*

Comment: для double, [следует `%lf` использовать](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/io/c/fscanf), [пример](https://ideone.com/Xui767)